# How to format the xml?

Tags: xml, c#-2.0

Hi
   I have an xml like below

```
<Root><First><id></id></First><Second><a>a</a><b>b</b></Second></Root>
```

I have to format it into

```
<Root><First><Second><a>a</a><b>b</b></Second><id></id></First></Root>
```

can any one tell me how to do this in c# 2.0. ?

Comment: Those two XML snippets are not equivalent. You want to move the `<Second>` element inside the `<First>`?

Comment: yes. Second xml snippet is the expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple using XML transformation, I think if you do something like this would work:
http://www.logiclabz.com/c/net-c-function-to-convert-xml-document-into-html-string-using-xslt.aspx

If don't know this, I think you have a great opportunity to learn it with you problem - it's very powerful!

Comment: this then maybe: http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=63

Comment: even though the the compiled version looks like it exists in 2.0 as well :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using DOM to transform the nodes.